# Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How to solve problem with migration on EF (Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes EF)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I developed the Telegram bot, I encountered the above mentioned problem with the migration of models to the database. I searched in Google and on this site, but could not find an answer that would solve my problem. Then, I found out that  before each action you just need to build a project or rebuild, then you need to Add-Migration, then again you need to build or rebuild the project and Update-Database, or restart VS. I hope someone comes in handy. Sorry for my bad english.